# How to add HTTP_USER_AGENT to my php form?

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Below is the code of my PHP form on my website (I didn't write it).
It works well (and I can see from which page the message is sent from) but when I receive an email I'd also like to see if the user sent the message from a smartphone, or from a mac, if he was using safari, or firefox, etc. I understand that `$_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];` is what I need.
The issue is that I'm not sure how/where to add this to the existing code as I'm not familiar with PHP syntax?
Many thanks for your help

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

  //send email
 mail( "djfhdss@gmail.com", "New message from: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['message']."\nFrom this page: ". str_replace("http://", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), "From:" . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "BCC: ffdssdd@gmail.com" );

}
?>
```

and the JS:

```
// Contact Form
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactfrm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;

        function isValidEmail(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };
        if (isValidEmail(email) && (message.length > 1) && (name.length > 1)) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sendfrm.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('button[name="submit"]').hide();
                    $('.error').hide()
                    $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.error').fadeIn(1000);
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: The same way you added `$_POST['name']` and all the other data you read from super globals.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't write the code. I'm a complete newbie in PHP. I added to my post the JS script linked to the form. I see there's already some checks performed on the email field. Do you think it's still vulnerable to header injection? Tks

Comment: @Greg - That's a completely separate question and probably better suited for the Code Review SE.

Comment: Thanks that's OK. Let's focus on the user agent addition ;-) Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add that to the line of the body in the `mail()`function. Is simplest, I don't know if I should answer or if I should close this as offtopic. But here you are the answer (follow the arrow for more clues):

```
mail( "djfhdss@gmail.com", "New message from: ".$_POST['name'], $_POST['message']."\nFrom this page: ". str_replace("http://", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])."\nAnd from this user agent: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "From:" . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . "BCC: ffdssdd@gmail.com" );
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```